# Deprecated: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated in

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

what is the best substitute for `settype()` in php 5.3.5 due to this error/warnings

> Deprecated: Call-time
>   pass-by-reference has been deprecated
>   in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MyWebInterface\includes\payroll_cutoff.inc.php
>   on line 217

Comment: Without knowing, what you are doing in `payroll_cutoff.inc.php`, its hard to say. Show us some code.

Comment: Without any context source code, it's hardly possible to answer your question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`settype()` hasn't been deprecated. Passing by reference at call time has been deprecated. You probably just want to remove the ampersand from in front of the first parameter to your `settype()` call.

That would be easier to tell for sure if you actually posted your code...

See the manual for [more information on references in general](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php), and passing by reference and the [deprecation of references in function calls in particular](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).

Comment: You are absolutely right Sir Matt, but instead of editing other forms that uses this function I just enable true ("allow_call_time_pass_reference") in php.ini

Comment: @aintgel, `allow_call_time_pass_reference` is very likely being *removed* in future PHP versions.  It will be better to fix your code.