# Getting Deprecated: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated when calling exec() Function

Tags: php

When running the following code:

```
<?php
    $output = array();
    exec("ping google.com", &$output);
    foreach ($output as $key => $value) {
        echo $value . "<br/>";
    }
?>
```

**Getting Deprecated**: as follows

```
 Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\my_test\ajax_loop.php on line 3.
```

Please help.

Comment: Read a note [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Comment: related questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665782/call-time-pass-by-reference-has-been-deprecated and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276451/deprecated-call-time-pass-by-reference-has-been-deprecated-in should have searched first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to drop the reference operator from `&$output` indeed.

Few tutorials provides the syntax of functions as follows (exec in this example).

```
string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] ) .
```

The '&' is not a reference operator, it only indicates that they are output variables, meaning you can expect the values of these variables to be populated with output data after the function call.
In this case *after the function call* the `$output` array will be filled with all lines of output from the commnad which you try to execute. The `$return_var` will have the return status.

Answer (score 0):

Just drop the reference operator, it is not needed:

```
...
exec("ping google.com", $output);
...
```